# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Web Deploy Fails

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, webdeploy

When I am trying to publish a website using the VS 2012 1-click web deployment tool, I am getting this **specific error**, even though I've installed Microsoft Web Deploy v3.5 :

> Package/Publish task Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeploy failed
>   to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly
>   installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is
>   recommended.

Steps that I've been doing:

1. Right-clicking on the project from the solution explorer and `Publish...`
2. Imported a `.publishsettings` file.
3. And next when I click the `Connection Tab` on the left-hand side, and click the **Validate Connection**, I get this:

   [image]

   and get the error above when I click further for details

Comment: Try re-install Web Deploy?